# Using post method to run an export takes too much time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed a Facebook application and I doing some offline analytics on the data from the dashboard.

I am using the Export API described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export

According your explanation the time it should take is about 1-2 hours but, I did it every day in the past week and it took me about 2 days to download each one of the exports.

My application don't have big amount of data, each export is small.

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong or maybe you have problem with the export service?

Comment: We don't know what you are doing so how will we tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have Facebook page which I sell there sport clothes.
Each day I would like to see the following parameters from the traffic:
- Timezone of the device
- Device platform - iOS,Android,PC
- Event_log_time - timestamp at which the event is logged

I make everyday POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[Application FBID]/analytics_app_events_exports 

with the following data:
access_token = {my access token}
start_ts = timestamp, begining of the day
end_ts = timestamp, end of the day

Then, after 5 hours I make get request to https://graph.facebook.com/V2.6/[Export FBID]?access_token={app access token}.

The response I get is:
"id": "##############",
"start_ts":"***",
"end_ts": "***",
"status": "SCHEDULED",
"column_names":[***],
"event_param_names":[{"event_name":[Event name]',"param_names":[Custom param names]}]


I have noticed that only after 2 Days the respone I get for the get request to https://graph.facebook.com/V2.6/[Export FBID]?access_token={app access token}
the status is COMPLETED. 

My question is why it takes to long? according to your API it should take about 1-2 hours.
```